# Subtracting and converting NSString and NSDate

Tags: ios, ios7, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have the following code:

```
NSString *startDate = @"2014-09-29 05:46:34 +000";

// Format the string
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, 19);
startDate = [startDate substringWithRange:range];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:startDate];

NSDate *trendDate = [dateFromString dateByAddingTimeInterval:-3600*12];

NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", trendDate];
```

My date string then ends up as:

```
@"2014-09-29 00:46:34 +000";
```

Why is it only minusing five hours instead of 12?

Comment: You should use NSDateComponents instead of using `dateByAddingTimeInterval:` of `NSDate`. Plus are you in a TimeZone with 7h of differences, since you didn't take count of the timezone of the `NSString` original date. What did print `dateFromString` before the time added?

Comment: I see I'm 7 hours behind GMT where the date being passed in is. Once I set the current date to GMT it works fine.

Comment: Beside your problem you may find these categories useful: http://journeytoios.wordpress.com/2014/09/05/nsdate-vs-nsstring-vice-versa/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its  because you are removing timezone from the date string that why you are getting wrong date

instead of removing +000 from your date string just replace your date formate.

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

With

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
```

**Removed code**

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, 19);
startDate = [startDate substringWithRange:range];
```

**Final Code**

```
NSString *startDate = @"2014-09-29 05:46:34 +000";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:startDate];

NSDate *trendDate = [dateFromString dateByAddingTimeInterval:-(3600*12)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting the substring from startDate string, try this date format:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"
```

Then

```
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:startDate];

NSDate *trendDate = [dateFromString dateByAddingTimeInterval:-3600*12];

NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:trendDate];
```